# Forcing page download in PHP

Tags: php

How do I force the browser to download the current page browsed to? A page with the header Content-type: text/plain for example using PHP?

If a user navigates to that page, a download box should appear (the browser download dialog with the usual "Save As".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from http://php.net/header

```
<?php
    // There is contention over if this MIME type is right, but just use it for now.
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.js"');

    readfile('file.js'); // Echo the file
?>
```

NOTE: this must be done before any other output (and can be about the only thing on the page, unless you want other output in your file).

Comment: if I am downloading a js file, should the url read something like: www.site.file.js?