# How to hide a download link

Tags: php, url, download

I have a PHP script that is supposed to allow the users to download a file without showing the URL. When I try out the following, the file I download is empty. Could someone please help?

```
<?php
$file_name = 'test.exe';
$file_url = 'https://www.example.com/' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
```

Comment: Is example.com your website or a remote location?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use like this

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary")
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.exe\""); 
echo readfile($url);
```

also content type based on your file application/zip, application/pdf etc

AND or better one for exe

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: I could not get it to work with the first method but the second method using "Location" seems to work well. Thank you.

Comment: Now a second problem arises. Using this new technique, it seems that the users can still see the download link in a download manager such as DAP. So is there really a way to hide the URL altogether?

Comment: it is software, i dont think so we can do it