# How change download url PHP

Tags: php, url, download, hide

i have must change (hide) a download url.

File to download: http://servdown.com/f1.rar
User is on page: http://mypage.com/down.php?id=1

But i don't need a redericting to domain with file ( servdown.com/f1.rar ).

Please help, i find [how to hide the actual download folder location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997516/how-to-hide-the-actual-download-folder-location) ,but that's bad.

Sorry for my bad English, thank

Comment: Why is that solution bad?

Comment: Becouse that's on one server and script downloading from "/x/b/down", i need downloading from "ww..../file.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some proxy type script which downloads the file remotely and then output the downloaded data ... There are many answers here , you just need to search you can get the exact code from there .

Here is one link :
[How to Hide link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873438/how-to-hide-a-download-link)

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Enter ur url:
$file = 'https://test.com/test.zip';
//get the file headers
$headers = get_headers ($file);
$Content_Type = '';
$Content_Length = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($headers); $i++) {
    $header = explode(":", $headers[$i]);
    //find content type in headers
    if ($header[0] == 'Content-Type') {
        $Content_Type = $headers[$i];
    }
    //find content length in headers
    if ($header[0] == 'Content-Length') {
        $Content_Length = trim($header[1]);
    }
}
// export name file from url
$filenameexploded = explode('/', $file);
$filenameexploded2 = explode('?', $filenameexploded[count($filenameexploded)-1]);
$filename = $filenameexploded2[0];
// send headrs
header($Content_Type);
header('Content-Length: ' . $Content_Length);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
// read file
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).