# trigger ctrl+s when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button.Now when I click on the button the cltrl+s will be pressed or tiggered.How to do that/ I have tried,

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 83, ctrlKey:true} );
    jQuery("body").trigger( e );
});
```

Comment: why you wanted to do that???

Comment: That won't make the browser save the page as the browser's key processing is done outside the JavaScript engine.

Comment: I want to save a xml page on click event...which normally opens in another tab.

Comment: just make an attachment page and download it. You can do it in PHP (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Comment: thats the problem...I want a pure javascript code...I don't want to use PHP,JSP or ASP.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<a href>` (html5) like:

```
<a href="downloads/file.xml" download>Download File</a>
```

And if you like to create an XML file in javascript and then save it by an a tag you can do:

```
var xml = '<xml><node1>bla</node1><node2 var="aa">abla</node2></xml>';
xml = btoa(xml); // Converts xml string to base64 (use atob to convert base64 back to string)
var a = document.createElement('a'); // Create A element
a.href = 'data:text/xml;base64,' + xml; // Set base64 encoded href
a.setAttribute('download', ''); // add html5 download tag
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('download xml file'); // Add link text
body.appendChild(a); // And add element to the page.
```

Paste this code in a html file and see for your self :)

Note: this code might not work in all browsers, tested with IE11 and Chrome

Comment: Wich browser are you using and wich version?
This works in Google Chrome (31)

Comment: Do you use the doctype <!DOCTYPE html> (html5)? Else this won't work.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp