# Display json data at web address

Tags: html, json, swagger, swagger-ui

I have what I think is a simple question about displaying a json file at a web address so that it can be recognized by Swagger UI.

The address http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs displays json data, and allows the file to be saved as a .json file.  I have been unable to replicate this using html.  This is what I tried:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
JSON DATA
</body>
```

The text gets displayed, however saving the page does not save it as a json file.

I should add that http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs is a directory, and http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs/pet is also json data.

Comment: Well, that is beacuse this is not a JSON file, maybe? That's HTML... What are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you want the saved file to contain only "`JSON DATA`", without the surrounding markup? Only put "`JSON DATA`" in the file :)

Comment: Yes, I just need http://domain.com/myfile to be able to be saved as json.  But http://domain.com/myfile should be a directory, with http://domain.com/myfile/other also containing json.  http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs does this.

Comment: If I just had data.json how could I get the web address to display this file by default (in the same way as index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output this as your file:

```
JSON DATA
```

:)

You don't need HTML in there. Just your JSON data. You need to use PHP or an .htaccess file to provide the content-type header (must be done before outputting anything to the browser!). An HTML header I don't think will work as expected, as the content of the page is still HTML regardless of *what you say it is*. Regardless of content type, the actual content starts with HTML and so CTLR+S will save it with HTML content.

If using PHP, this file will work for you (save it as index.php and it will be the default when requesting a folder, as you requested in a comment on your question):

```
<?php header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf8'); ?>JSON DATA
```

You can put a linebreak after `?>` and before `JSON DATA` if you prefer, PHP will ignore a single linebreak after a closing PHP tag.

This will make the browser detect the source is application/json, as opposed to interpreting it as an HTML file. However I suspect most browsers don't know what to do with a json file. If you want to force-download a file, (even suggesting a name like "my-amazing-file.json"), that can be done too:

[How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)