# how to download file with php?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to solution download file into php
I am using this way to download file but getting issue download file code

```
$filename = '[file name].[extension]';

$file="application/[extension]";


if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
```

problem:

Comment: Have you used headers to download it ?

Comment: I think there's something missing after "problem:"

Comment: check below link which will be useful for your problem
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php[link]

Comment: you will see popup to save the file

Comment: pls check my answer to download file using headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Follow the instruction by variable.... Use file path not filename

```
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-length: ".filesize($dest_file_path));
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dest_file_name.'"');
        readfile($dest_file_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic example to download file -

```
$file="http://example.com/filename.mp3"; // your filename with path
header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file)); 
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: you have to give file name with path in $file not directory...remove songs from $file and assign filename under songs directory

Comment: i am not getting your problem with database...is your file stored in database ?

Comment: ok...get that file from database and assign it to $file variable

Comment: why after download ?? you have to fetch it before your download script. You need to post another question if you want to know about fetch data from database

Comment: still your question is unclear...you want to download all the files from songs folder ??