# Save video from webpage html link

Tags: html, video

I am trying to setup on my website where I can view a video in low resolution for space saving purposes, then if someone likes the video, I have added into the webpage a link for them to download the full hi-res video.  The problem seems to be that no matter what I try I cannot get anything to actually download to my pc from the host server webpage video directory.  I have tried many different options that I have found by googling the net.  For instance

```
<a href="http://ccfga.us/videos/cbn_davidgarner_011715.mp4">David Garner</a>
```

If you are using Opera this will "Stream" and play in your Opera Browser, It will not work on IE11, Google Chrome, Firefox or Safari.  And Streaming is not what I wanted anyway, I want someone to be able to download the file to their harddrive to watch later.

Can anyone help me figure out how to be able to download to my pc from the webpage Download link?  The primary browser I would like to use is IE, however I am trying to also go for multi-browser support.

*** Edit ***
After clicking on the link in IE11 it appeared to be thinking so I let it run and after about 5 minutes it started streaming.  But I still cant download to my pc the file.

Comment: Use the `content-disposition` header to suggest that a browser downloads the video rather than open it in a player. Alternatively, consider using the <video /> element instead, so people can simply watch it in the browser without opening any other programs or downloading anything.

Comment: See this question, it will learn you how to fore the browser to download your video [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)