# how to make a link download directly a pdf?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need to make a link downloadable to PDF, the solution can be in Javascript, HTML or PHP.

Things you have to know to answer this question:

1- I tried add the attribute "download" in  and its only works in chrome

2- I don't have the pdf file in my server, i only have a link

3- The name of the file change because the link is generated dynamically

4- I don't want the pdf open in the browser in another tab and i don't want to open in the same page. Only download.

EDIT:

5 -i don't want to open a page and start to download i need to wait the user click to do that

Comment: You would need to pull the remote pdf to your server in order to server it as a download.

Comment: can you show some code ? what you tried?

Comment: @Kamran <a href="example.com/blablah.pdf" download>  Descargar PDF</a>

Comment: TESTED 
<?php
function _Download($f_location, $f_name){
  $file=uniqid().'.pdf';
  file_put_contents($file,file_get_contents($f_location));
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($f_name));
  readfile($file);
 }

 _Download($_GET['file'], "file.pdf");

?>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=document.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("document.pdf");
?>
```

Credits: http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Comment: This will actually often open the PDF in the browser, because of the `content-type: application/pdf`, so switching that out with `application/octet-stream` would do the trick.

Comment: @EmilIngerslev: You can verify with a similar code here: [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm)

Comment: @EmilIngerslev — No, it won't. Content-disposition: attachment will cause it to download the file. You don't need to lie about the content-type.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the file is a URL on another server, so it ends up being pretty expensive (in terms of bandwith) and slow.

Comment: That will work in those browsers/systems that respect the attachment header, but through experience I've seen that it isn't always the case. The other header, not specifying it's a pdf, but just a download works, even in old browsers.

Comment: @Quentin Have you checked out the other SO on almost the same issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the following PHP script:

```
$file_url = 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/file.exe';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
```

*credits: [How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)*

Comment: I'm a little confused, if i use that script, when the user click in <a href="http://www.myremoteserver.com/file.exe"> will download automaticly?

Comment: You have to add this to a separate php script. An option is to read the file from a url path or query string.

Comment: ok i think is working in a bad way. but working, that code print this http://screencloud.net/v/szz4 in the page and not download the file