# How do you use a download on a page as a source

Tags: javascript, html, download

Sorry if my question is unclear, it's hard for me to explain.

Basicaly I want this:

```
<a href="the_other_webpage" download>download file</a>
```

to download the file this webpage automatically downloads:

**html**:

```
<a id="download" href="download_file_url" download hidden></a>
```

**javascript**:

```
document.getElementById('download').click();
```

Comment: I guess this is impossible. You can do this in PHP, though. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php).

Comment: you need to name a file in the `download` attrib, then click will work: http://pagedemos.com/yp6rtseyjae5/