# PHP convert comma delimited string to CSV file

Tags: php

I have a delimited string coming from a service, I want to convert this delimited string with headers to a downlodable CSV file.

```
    empId,empName,salary,depName,depId
    1,John,20000,IT,2
```

Could someone help me with a code snippet/reference.

Comment: Isn't this a CSV already? Do you just want to [force a download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)?

Answer (score 1):

change header first

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.csv"');
    echo 'empId,empName,salary,depName,depId';
    echo '1,John,20000,IT,2';   
?>
```

and then echo your output.

Comment: Sry, the service returns a CSV, the problem is the response goes to jQuery failCallback, I can see the CSV string in jqXHR.

Comment: set this also in header("Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/") and try

Comment: no, it doesnt help, i think something should be added to jquery get parameters, trying with several options like dataType: "text/csv", still facing problem

Comment: does it coming into sucess callback ?

Comment: i suggest to use iframe or window.location not to use jquery ajax. it will definitely work