# How to use AWS S3 for image processing (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

For my website i want to store all image using AWS S3 service using API.

How to do that thing via API/SDK

1) How to upload image/file in different folder using API (from my website).

2) How to resize/crop image on the fly. eg 50x50 px, 250x250 px.

3) Force download.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you've already looked through the AWS SDK for PHP, what have you got so far? As for resizing and cropping, I believe your application's server should be taking care of that and then send to your S3 bucket.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think AWS has a built-in feature to resize any stored image in S3. As [eldblz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758766/eldblz) mentioned, you have to do the resizing on your own. You can use S3 stream wrapper.

The S3 stream wrapper is pretty amazing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

It will allow you to use built-in PHP functions like file_get_contents and file_put_contents.

1. Get details of the original file:

   ```
   # If you have stream wrapper enabled, 
   # getimagesize will get information from the S3
   # you have to pass the S3 URI though
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize('s3://bucket/key');

   # making the new image 50x50
   $new_width = 50;
   $new_height = 50;

   $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
   ```
2. Get the image data with file_get_contents(or fopen):

   ```
   $data = file_get_contents('s3://bucket/key');
   ```
3. create an image resource from the data and resize:

   ```
   $source = imagecreatefromstring($data); 

   # Resize
   imagecopyresized($new_image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
   ```
4. Output:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   imagejpeg($thumb);
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so the answer cannot be precise. I'll give some advice or library to start:

1. *How to upload image/file in different folder using API (from my website).*

This library should be a nice place to start working with S3 and files:
https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

2. *How to resize/crop image on the fly. eg 50x50 px, 250x250 px.*

This should do the trick: https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize 
Or you can try PHP Imagick: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

3. *Force download.*

Stackoverflow already has the answer for you:
[How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: 1st and 3rd answer are fine.

2nd > resize/crop is for remote image (hosted in asw ). eg ... asw.com/abc.jpg?h=200&w=200&q=100

Comment: You can use s3 library to get object S3::getObject($bucketName, $uploadName) then use the image library