# Forcing file download in PHP corrupts zip files

Tags: php, download

My PHP script forces a file to download, which all works fine, but when forcing zip files to download, they corrupt.

When I try and open the zip file locally it just converts from a `.zip` to a `.zip.cpgz`

If I download the file from a direct URL the zip file is fine, so I know it's only corrupting during the push/download phase.

Here's my code

```
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"_zip_download.zip\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force file download with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

For zip file you can set `header("Content-Type: application/zip");`

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"_zip_download.zip\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file));
readfile($zip_file);
exit;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that has made no difference.

Comment: Do you use `readfile` function? Can you try to download file in different browser?

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem. It was an issue with headers being sent before the file.

Comment: Excuse me @DanielWilliams but headers are supposed to be sent before the file.

Comment: I mean, there was something else being printed to screen before PHP sent headers.