# HTML Download not working

Tags: html, download

I have a code set up to download a file on my FTP, but when I click on the link it tries to take me to the url and not download the file. What am I missing? I've tried every version of the HTML code and nothing works.

```
<a href="/finaledit/murphy_drive.mp4" target="_blank"><span style="color: #ff0000;">Click here to download package</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, add the `download` attribute to it. Like this:

```
<a download href="/finaledit/murphy_drive.mp4" target="_blank"><span style="color: #ff0000;">Click here to download package</span></a>
```

Comment: `download` attribute is not supported in IE and Safari

Comment: It's the only way I know with HTML. With php you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php