# Unable to download file in php

Tags: php, download, force-download

I have a file download code [using php](https://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/creating-one-time-download-links/) and my code at download page is follows.

```
 if (file_exists($strDownload)) {

    //get the file content
     $strFile = file_get_contents($strDownload);

       //set the headers to force a download
      header("Content-type: application/force-download");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . str_replace(" ", "_", $arrCheck['file_name']) . "\"");

      //echo the file to the user
     echo $strFile;

     //update the DB to say this file has been downloaded
       mysql_query("xxxxxxxx");

           exit;
     }
```

Where the function `file_exists()` passed with valid check and my `$strDownload` variable will be something like `/home/public_html/uploads/myfile.zip` which is located in server folder. But when I trying to download the file instead of downloading, the page displays the full encrypted source of the file. How can I make it downloadable?

**EDIT:** for the information, myself trying to use this bit of code inside the wordpress system and my file path will be something like `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/myfile.zip`. Also in the above mentioned code myself checking the `file_exists()` condition for the server path which is already mentioned above and it returns `1` as desired.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        if (file_exists($file)) 
        {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Same result as mentioned in question. Displaying the source code of the file instead of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using the above bit of codes at beginning of php page. Ie, before declaring the famous wordpress tag `get_header();`

If we use the above code after `get_header();` tag of wordpress, it results in the opening of page first and hence it writes the source of the file in the page instead of downloading since the meta tags are already set.