# Download file via PHP from FTP, like normally downloading a file?

Tags: php, download, ftp

I am currently trying to retrieve a file from an FTP-Server in order to make it accessible for the user to download. `ftp_get()` writes it to a path on the local machine, yes, but what I want is that it also shows up in the download history and counts as "normal" download from the internet but I didn't figure out how to do this yet. I also tried to link directly to the file in PHP with `header("Location: ftp://username:password@ftp.server.com/myfile.file")` but this was resulting in the browser showing the files contents (which I didn't want). Did I miss any `header`-Parameters ? Or is there a completely different way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to "redirect" a user to a file so he can download it using FTP. This is a HTTP-thing. Browsers provides FTP features and make it look like HTTP but, in fact, those are different stuff.

If this file is only accessible through FTP and it is on a remote server, the only way I can imagine so you cand 'redirect' this download to the user is:

- Download the file from the FTP to your application server through FTP in PHP;
- Send it to the user using PHP and appropriate file headers, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263943/2802720

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! :)