# downloading pdf files using php

Tags: php, pdf, download

I have PHP files stored on my server, and their names in the mysql database, I want to download those files. What code should I write for the same? I am using PHP as coding language. Please help.

Comment: just select your question title and right click and click search on google, you will get solution on first link.

Comment: @KevinNelson I was about to use your possible duplicate to close this question, but the OP's story seems to go further: *"and their names in the mysql database"* - TBH, I'm "on the fence" with this one.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, hmm...yeah...maybe I jumped the gun because it was a question without more details of what areas he's struggling with.  I was assuming since he put the names in the DB that he knows how to get the names out, and he just didn't know how to do the output.

Comment: @KevinNelson Maybe not (jumped the gun), given the answers (so far) below.

Comment: Other example with DB query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730545/php-how-to-make-browser-to-download-file-on-click

Comment: @KevinNelson I used the duplicate you originally marked it off with as a possible duplicate and the additional link you included above, *thanks*.

Comment: @rugwed, I'm not trying to beat on you, but for future reference, this may help you ask questions that don't get voted down: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No problem, I will keep it in the mind henceforth. Thanks though. @KevinNelson

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'send_me.pdf';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Obviously, set `$file` to the file name.

Read more about the use of [readfile here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="$result->pathToServer">Download</a>`?

Literally just make a link the stored file.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents("PDFName.pdf", fopen("http://someurl/PDFName.pdf", 'r'));
```

You really should show what you have done so far/researched online before asking a question!
This will download the file PDFName.pdf from the url http://someurl/PDFName.pdf and put it into the same directory as the script is in.