# How to download a file in php

Tags: php, json, extjs, http-headers

I have this function in php for downloading a file, the file will be encrypted with data, and then be downloaded

Class: Connect is simply connection to database

```
class License extends Connect {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

        public function getLicense($vars){
//        file_put_contents( "/var/log/datapost/clientinfo.log", date('r'). " ". var_export($vars,true) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        $sql = "select * from License where license_id={$vars->data->license_id}";
        $res = $vars->db->query( $sql );
        if($obj=$res->fetch_object()){

            $filename = "License".$vars->data->license_id.".json";

            // get the private key
            $pk = file_get_contents("/var/www/datapost/clientinfo/keys/key1.pem");
            // // private key
            $res = openssl_get_privatekey($pk,"passsword");
            // // encrypt it
            $x=openssl_private_encrypt( json_encode($obj),$crypttext,$res);

            // save the encryption
            // 

file_put_contents("/var/www/datapost/clientinfo/license/license{$vars->data->license_id}}.json",$crypttext);
//            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
//            header('Expires: 0');
//            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
//            header('Pragma: public');
//            header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($crypttext));
            echo $crypttext;
            file_put_contents("/var/log/datapost/{$filename}", $crypttext, fopen("http://192.168.200.114/var/log/datapost/{$filename}", 'r' ));
            flush();
            file_put_contents( "/var/log/datapost/clientinfo.log", date('r'). " WOOHOO! $crypttext" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        }
        else {
            file_put_contents( "/var/log/datapost/clientinfo.log", date('r'). " AAARG SHIT ".var_export($res,true) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }
    }
```

but for some reason it is not workiing, the data is being sent in http request but no file is being downloaded with data, any help appreciated

Here is ajax request in extjs application, (on button click)

```
onButtonClick7: function(button, e, eOpts) {
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'system/index.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        class: 'License',
        method: 'getLicense',
        data: Ext.encode({
        license_id: Ext.getCmp('overviewGrid').selection.data.license_id
            })
        },
        success: function( response ){
            var object = Ext.decode( response.responseText, true );
            //Ext.getStore('LicenseAllStore').reload();
            //             window.open('http://192.168.200.114/datapost/clientinfo/license/BLAH_BLAGH3.json');
        },
        failure: function( response ){
            var object = Ext.decode( response.responseText, true );
            Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Status', object.message );
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: did you verify it's actually going into the if block? place a var_dump in it or step through the code with  debugger.

Comment: yes, I saw the response from the request, the 'echo $crypttext'

Comment: the network request is there, but no file downloaded

Comment: yes, please verify the request actually triggers the if block outputting the headers. you are interested in the response, not the request.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean the actual encrypted text response is seen

Comment: change the headers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php. Does it work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it can be done like this way :

**By USING CURL :**

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = "http://someurl.com/afile.zip";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "/asubfolder/afile.zip";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

**By USING `file_put_contents()` :**

Since PHP 5.1.0, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) supports writing piece-by-piece by passing a stream-handle as the `$data` parameter:

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
```

From the manual:

> If ***data*** [that is the second argument] is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of that stream will be copied to the specified file. This is similar with using
>   [`stream_copy_to_stream()`](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream).

**Another Part Of Your Question :**

Since you are trying to convert an array into json and then save that json code into a text file so,
Here is an approach exactly that how you can do it :

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('team_name' => "Team 1", 'wins' => "3", 'losses' => "0" ), //3
    array('team_name' => "Team 2", 'wins' => "2", 'losses' => "1" ), //2
    array('team_name' => "Team 3", 'wins' => "1", 'losses' => "2" ), //1
    array('team_name' => "Team 4", 'wins' => "0", 'losses' => "3" ), //1
    array('team_name' => "Team 5", 'wins' => "3", 'losses' => "0" ), //3
    array('team_name' => "Team 6", 'wins' => "2", 'losses' => "1" ) ); //2

//if you want to just print the array here
echo json_encode($data);

// If you want to save the array into a text file
$json_file = fopen("array_into_json.txt" , "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($json_file,json_encode($data). "\r\n");
fclose($json_file);

?>
```

**Note :** You can do the same with the array which you fetch from your database with this code just replacing the `$data` array with your MySQLi array..!

**Live Code :** https://eval.in/562247

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the OP, but I think the issue is not writing the file but forcing the file download dialogue.

Comment: I made the file_put_content changes but no change, i will keep trying to figure the problem

Comment: Ok so I put the file the file with the contents into a writable folder and it worked, however It didnt download the file straight after, I used window.open in javascript but the error said file not found, the file I outputted is in error log directory, just for now

Comment: added  file_put_contents("/path/to/log/{$filename}", $crypttext, fopen("http://example.com/path/to/log/{$filename}", 'r' )); below echo $crypttext

Comment: how do I download that just added readfile(/path/to/log/$filename); not successfull

Comment: @AndrewBarker : I am gonna have to take a look over your code besides just make sure that you share your whole code in your question so that I don't have any problem in checking your code live..!

Comment: does it make sense, as you see I did change a few things since last post, those being the file_put_contents and fopen

Comment: still cant get the file to download

Comment: @AndrewBarker : Have you tried with simple function without encrypting etc and all those other things..???

Comment: @AndrewBarker : Also I am not getting that exactly what are you really trying to do? Can you properly explain with some example that what are you trying to do so may be I can then try to rewrite full code for you..!

Comment: So I havea grid in sencha, this grid has records next it I have a button that has the ajax request above linked to it, this ajax request is linked to the php function, now when I click the button the selectedRecord should be downloaded, the download needs to be downloaded in the php

Comment: when i say the record will be downloaded I mean all the information from the sql query will be formatted into json and put into file and downloaded,

Comment: Simply you want to select all from your MySQL table and then encode the array of data into json and put that json data into a text file right???

Comment: @AndrewBarker : I updated the answer take a look at the answer now and let me know if it solves your problem and then you should mark the answer and consider this question solved..!