# How to trigger download of a file using php from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, download

I use code from [How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

```
<?php

require('Service.php');
$service = new Service('config.json', getcwd() . '/..');
if ($service->valid_token($_GET['token']) && isset($_GET['filename'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($_GET['filename']) . "\"");
    readfile($_GET['filename']); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
}

?>
```

and call it from javascript using jQuery get

```
var filename = cwd + '/' + cmd.args[0];
$.get('lib/download.php', {filename: filename, token: token}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

but the file is not downloaded. I only get normal ajax response. How can I download a file using javascript? I need php script for this because I want to download php files or cgi scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with ajax. You can open a form in a new window pointing to the script and have it close when the download is ready.

Or even use `window.location` with javascript to open the script in a new window.