# csv/xls file not downloading in client server

Tags: php, server

I wrote PHP code to export data to .csv file.The exported .csv file was downloadable on my own PC. But in client's server, the .csv file was not downloadable, it was in readable format (the browser can read and print the file contents like a .html file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Comment: Simply send headers: `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="report.csv"); `

Comment: Still facing that problem only. I was new bee in PHP. I added "header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv');" this code in server side file. Its shows like raw data but not download csv file.

Comment: Seems like Your files has issues with UTF8 BOM in file that makes data to be outputted before headers are sent

Comment: If there is an issue means then why it was working in local server??

Comment: Just open Your file in normal PHP editor: VS Code, Sublime, Atom and find UTF8 BOM symbol. Mostly reasons of such anomaly is that evaluated code first outputs bom with text html headers and then comes result of code execution.

Comment: Oh... Also please add Your code in the question, maybe solution will be simple.

Comment: $xl_selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `Mid` ASC";
 $connquery = mysqli_query($connection,$xl_selectQuery);

 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($connquery))
 {
 echo $res['Member_Name'];
 }


 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv');

Comment: Ohhh man... Add that headers before doing echo!)))

Comment: Thank you so much got output!!!

Answer (score 1):

Headers come first:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=members.csv');

$q = 'SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `Mid` ASC';
$q = mysqli_query($connection, $q);

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) :

  echo $record['Member_Name'];

endwhile;
```