# How to force download googlevideo.com link in php and html

Tags: javascript, php

i would like to force download the **googlevideo.com  url** *with php or js* rather than playing in the browser....

url is:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9hjfn7zqOZINb2UmY352yVU3XWLE7vvtDRHiWm9KPwd6hIBultO5yFea0yzGkwNdci9c-Y1SJINEN6dqoqrTqFI2B57d9Di_tODQ2Tsrp0nXS9XCfU9nCvxp1ONbQoquLFeeesa3iw=m37
```

my code:

```
<button class="button button1" ><a target="_self" href="<?php $data = json_decode($getGP, true); echo $data[0]['file'];?>">1080p Download Link</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like here you can find a proper answer to your question:
[How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

In short words - there is no simple way with html-tag or with URL modification to tell the browser that you want to download the video.

In the thread from the link above, there is a PHP code to create own script that will download video from link and put it back to the user's browser as a file.