# how do you transfer file/image from server to client pc

Tags: php, file

can someone help me find the best and easiest method to transfer a file/image from a server in php to a client pc, it needs to download/transfer the file to the clients computer when the function is executed
this is the function i need it in:

```
<?php
function download($content){
file_put_contents('./img/meme-temp.png', file_get_contents($content));
`code to download file`
unlink('./img/meme-temp.png');
}
?>
```

it needs to be in either html, javascript or php
i have tried varius methods including using the html download property and javascript autoclick on outputted downloadlinks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)