# Word document Base64 encoded string downloads as zip file

Tags: php, html, base64

I have a base64 encoded string converted with the php function below.

```
public function convert_image_to_base64($file_path){
    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($file_path);
    $data = file_get_contents($file_path);
        
    return 'data:'. $mime . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);      
}
```

I want to download the file in a browser with the below html

```
<a href="<?= $base64_file ?>" target="blank">Download</a>
```

When I click, the link downloads a **zip file**.

This is the start of the resulting base64 string

> data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAI

I want to download the exact **.docx or .doc file** uploaded

I searched on stackoverflow and other forums but none of them address this exact problem. I also don't want to decode the file before submitting the html.

Comment: it would be a bad idea to put the full file in a base64 url inside a page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Comment: @DanielA.White There is a security reason why I am choosing to put the file in the html. It's going to be confidential documents.

Comment: that isn't a good enough reason - theres ways to secure it still with authentication and authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the file extension of the downloaded file was not added in the base64 file downloaded. I solved the problem by forcing the name of the downloaded file using the html below from this link. Reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp)

```html
<a href="<?= $base64_file ?>" download="file.docx" target="blank">Download</a>
```