# safari browser opens the generated xls file but i cannot force it to download ( ios )

Tags: php, ios, cordova

i have generated a xls file in a **Cordova App** Using **PHP** and i want to download it. It is perfectly working in **Android** ,  In the case of ios the file is opening on the browser **But not downloading**.

Here my code is.

```
 <?php
 $output .= '"S.No","Invoice No","Invoice Date"'."\n";
 $output .= '"S.No","Invoice No","Invoice Date"'."\n";
 $output .= '"S.No","Invoice No","Invoice Date"'."\n";
 $output .="\n";
 $date=date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
 $filename =  "report".$date.".csv";
 header('Content-type: application/xls');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
 echo $output;
 exit;
 ?>
```

Comment: Try `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`, instead of a content type the browser might think it should handle itself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263943/1427878

Comment: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` not working